# How to delete lines in a text file if they start with a number using a shell script

Tags: shell, text

Id like to know a good way to read a file and delete all lines of text that start with numbers, i.e [0-9] using some shell scripting. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this:

```
grep -v '^[0-9]' input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed '/^[0-9]/d' file > outfile
```

If you have GNU sed, the original file itself can be updated:

```
sed -i '/^[0-9]/d' file
```